# ASP.NET C# Data Access Layer function issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

I am using the 3-tier architecture in my .NET site. Currently in my DAL (Data Access Layer) I have Load, Update, Insert and Delete which is all working fine. However I now want to create a function to grab data by an email address.

Below is my `load`, `insert` and `getByEmailAddress` that reside in my Data Access Layer

```
 public DataTable Load()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyGlobals.conString);
        SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("administratorGetAll", conn);
        dAd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            dAd.Fill(dSet, "AdministratorsTable");
            return dSet.Tables["AdministratorsTable"];
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dSet.Dispose();
            dAd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to load records from database by email address
    /// </summary>
    public int GetByEmailAddress(AdministratorsBO administrator)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyGlobals.conString);
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("administratorGetByEmailAddress", conn);
        dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", administrator.EmailAddress);

            SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);

            dAd.Fill(dSet, "AdministratorsTable");
            return Convert.ToInt32(dSet.Tables["AdministratorsTable"]);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dSet.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to insert records into database
    /// </summary>
    public int Insert(AdministratorsBO administrator)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyGlobals.conString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("administratorInsert", conn);
        dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", administrator.UserName);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", administrator.EmailAddress);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", administrator.Password);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", administrator.FirstName);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", administrator.LastName);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isActive", administrator.IsActive);
            return dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dCmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Next is my Business Access Layer:

```
public DataTable Load()
    {
        AdministratorsDAL aDAL = new AdministratorsDAL();
        try
        {
            return aDAL.Load();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            aDAL = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load records from database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DataTable GetByEmailAddress(AdministratorsBO administrator)
    {
        AdministratorsDAL aDAL = new AdministratorsDAL();
        try
        {
            return aDAL.GetByEmailAddress(administrator);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            aDAL = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert records into database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    public int Insert(AdministratorsBO administrator)
    {
        AdministratorsDAL aDAL = new AdministratorsDAL();
        try
        {
            return aDAL.Insert(administrator);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            aDAL = null;
        }
    }
```

The Load and Insert are pretty standard and work. However the `getByEmailAddress` is not configured properly. I tried mixing code from the load and insert but I was unsuccessful. Can anyone give me a hint, idea or something that would fix this so I can use `getByEmailAddress`

By the way, that function is supposed to hit a stored procedure that gathers all information by whatever emailAddress input is sent through.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "not configured properly."  How is it not working?  When you debug into it, where does it fail?

Comment: the catch { throw; } statements are not required.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the error happening and where does it throw (in BusinessLayer or DAL)?

Comment: In the BAL, the try/catch/finally is not required.  Note that aDAL = null, does nothing.  Just do return (new AdministratorsDal()).Load();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Business Layer is returning a DataTable for GetByEmailAddress but your Data Access Layer is returning an int for GetByEmailAddress.  Don't you want in your DAL:

```
public DataTable GetByEmailAddress(AdministratorsBO administrator)
```

and the return changed to:

```
return dSet.Tables["AdministratorsTable"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring from you business layer you should be returning a datatable not an integer

```
public DataTable GetByEmailAddress(AdministratorsBO administrator)
{
    Using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyGlobals.conString))
    {
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("administratorGetByEmailAddress", conn);
        dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();

        dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", administrator.EmailAddress);

        SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);

        dAd.Fill(dSet);
        return dSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```